# What are different types of match in Firebase Storage Security Rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage, firebase-security

What are different types of match in Firebase Storage Security Rules? 
It seems very confusing how to match path in the security rules.
Please Help. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In firebase storage security rules, `"match"` is a keyword.
`"match"` is used to match a specific storage path so that you can apply a rule to that location. Every path starts with a `'/'` followed by path segments.

> There are 3 types of path segments:

1. **Single Segment:** reference to specific file. syntax - `match /images/profile.png`  (only matches /images/profile.png)
2. **Single Segment Wildcard:** reference to all path at particular path level. syntax - `match /images/{images}`
   (matches /images/xyz.png, but, doesn't match /images/screenshots/xyz.png)
3. **Multi Segment Wildcard:** reference to all path at or below particular path. syntax - `match /images/{images=**}`
   (matches /images/xyz.png, and also matches /images/screenshots/xyz.png)

Hope it helps.

[Reference for more info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage/#path_segments)